# Setting up SSL with letsencrypt and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, ubuntu-18.04

It’s the first time I setup SSL, I chose to use letsencrypt.

I have an Angular application running on https, and that is working. I also have REST APIs implemented in NodeJS, and I am stuck on being able to provide them securely. The service is running on port 8443, and if I disable the certificate request they work (this to explain that no change to the code should be done).

The NodeJS code is as follows:

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(<path_to_privkey.pem>, ‘utf8’);
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(<path_to_cert.pem>, ‘utf8’);
const ca = fs.readFileSync(<path_to_chain.pem>, ‘utf8’);

let activateHttps = true;

const credentials = {
key: privateKey,
cert: certificate,
ca: ca,
requestCert: activateHttps,
rejectUnauthorized: activateHttps
};
```

APIs are accessed with https://IP:8443/api/. Routing is implemented in NodeJS.

The configuration on sites-enabled/000-default.conf is as follows:

```
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
<VirtualHost :>
ServerName 
ServerAlias 
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog {APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log CustomLog {APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile <path_to_cert>
SSLCertificateKeyFile <path_to_key>
SSLCertificateChainFile <path_to_chain>
<Location /api>
ProxyPass https:/<ip>/:8443/api #tried redirect but not working! So I access with the IP
ProxyPassReverse https://<ip>:8443/api
```

The NodeJS application is hosted in another directory, different from /var/www/html.

I can’t figure out why https is not working when providing APIs. Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't need https in node if you serve it through apache/nginx. You just have to remember to generate the right urls in the node.

Comment: ok, so you are suggesting to do something like: ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/, right? and serve with http. Well, that was a trial, and didn't work

Comment: 1: Configure apache https server. 2: add prxy pass to http node app. eg: https://serverfault.com/questions/331161/how-to-configure-apache-to-act-as-an-ssl-proxy-to-an-application-server

Comment: Thank you, you were almost right. I updated the .htaccess file as suggested, but then I needed to provide the APIs as HTTPS for the mixed content (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549323/the-page-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-xmlhttprequest-endpoin?rq=1, of course you can't provide resources in HTTP if you ensure SSL).

The rule that I added is: RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ <http://ip>/$1 [P,L]

By doing that, it keeps the https but accesses the http API. Thank you again.